# Run Bitcoin and BitcoinCash in same server

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-cash, bitcoin-cli

I use debian 9
I have compile 2 files:

bitcoinCashd -version
Bitcoin ABC Daemon version v0.16.2.0-6af5e93

bitcoind -version
Bitcoin Core Daemon version v0.15.1

So i need run in same server. Can some one help?

maybe need rename some executable files and connected both wallets on different ports?

Maybe good step by step manual

Answer (score 2):

The PORT (to receive data) for both of them is **8332** by default. So you must determine the PORT in the config file for one or both of them like this:

For BitcoinCash:

```
server=1
daemon=1
rpcuser=xxx
rpcpassword=zzz
rpcport=8355
port=6950
```

For Bitcoin:

```
server=1
daemon=1
rpcuser=aaaaaa
rpcpassword=bbbb
rpcport=8320
port=5380
```

Don't forget to allow the ports by firewall and specify different data directories for them.

Answer (score 0):

The two implementations are still kind of competing for the name bitcoin, hence they could use the same daemon name and same folders.

Remember this during installation as well and make sure you are creating executables with different names.

When you launch any of the two daemons, by default, it will try to load the configuration from `~/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf`, which means that for one daemon you will have to create a specific directory with a dedicated config file.

```
bitcoind --config ~/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf
bchd --config ~/.bch/bch.conf
```

***bitcoin.conf***

```
daemon=1 
server=1
port=8332
rpcport=5555
datadir=~/.bitcoin/
```

***bch.conf***

```
daemon=1
server=1
port=8333
rpcport=6666
datadir=~/.bch/
```

The ports and the directory are just for explanatory purposes, the only important thing is that they have to differ between the two configuration files